# MongoDB grouping results based on greater than expression

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a ton of records in a collection that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a95cf7790bd8fbf1c6a39da"),
    "dmb_reviewerID" : "AB9S9279OZ3QO",
    "dmb_asin" : "0078764343",
    "dmb_reviewerName" : "Alan",
    "dmb_helpful" : [ 
        1, 
        1
    ],
    "dmb_reviewText" : "I haven't gotten around to playing the campaign but the multiplayer is solid and pretty fun. Includes Zero Dark Thirty pack, an Online Pass, and the all powerful Battlefield 4 Beta access.",
    "dmb_overall" : 5.0,
    "dmb_summary" : "Good game and Beta access!!",
    "dmb_unixReviewTime" : 1373155200,
    "dmb_reviewTime" : "07 7, 2013"
}
```

I need to find all of the product IDs (dmb_asin) which have 200 reviews or more.

So far, I've managed to count them and return a sum using an aggregate, but I can't figure out how to only show those that are greater than 200.

My code:

```
aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$dmb_asin",
    reviews: {
      $addToSet: "$dmb_asin"
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1,},


}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (if I correctly understand you)

```
aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$dmb_asin',
      count: {
          $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
          $gte: 200
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {$group: {
             _id: "$dmb_asin",
              reviews: {
                       $addToSet: "$dmb_asin"
               },
             count: {
                     $sum: 1,}
       }},
       {$match:{"reviews":{$gte:200}}}

])
```

Comment: Not returning any results, unfortunately

Comment: Note that you need to replace `collection` with your collection name. Also,  if possible please import your collection and share the json so that we can use the data set to try and see results.